# How can I make the line segments' color smooth in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I found that the figure produced by `\addplot[mesh]` is composed of the line segments having the different colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        samples=50,
        point meta rel=axis wide,
        point meta=y,
        ]
    \addplot[mesh,thick] {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produce
[image]

The color transition is not smooth. I want to make the line color smooth and I rewrite the above code as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        samples=50,
        point meta rel=axis wide,
        point meta=y,
        colormap access=direct,
        shader=interp
        ]
    \addplot[mesh,thick] {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That produces the line in the same color. How can make the line color varied according to the point meta and the color transition smooth?

Comment: What's wrong with increasing the number of `samples`? There's no need to increase it excessively if you just want the eye to perceive smooth variation of color.

Comment: You might want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137438/116936

Comment: The problem is, the shaders are meant for the facets of a surface, not for curves, or meshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try this at home ! (because it is silly `;)`... !)

Seriously, you should just increase the `samples` number of your curve.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [
        samples=51,
        view={0}{0},
        ]
    \addplot3
    [
      surf,
      line width=2mm,
      point meta=z,
      shader=interp,
      samples y=2,
      y domain=0:.05,
    ]
      ({x-y*cos(deg(x)},0,{sin(deg(x))+y});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But what if I have a table with values instead of a function, so that I cannot simply increase the number of samples?

Comment: very late suggestion... but just use linear interpolation to add more samples to your table.