# Draw single arrow shape with corners in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw an arrow with corners in TikZ, which looks the following (should have the same width everywhere):

[image]

I am aware of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388847/drawing-a-corner-curved-arrow-shape), but it makes the whole arrow colored because of the thick line width instead of having a white arrow with a colored border around it.

MWE for drawing an arrow without a corner:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node (arrow) at (0,0) {};
    \node [single arrow, draw, minimum height=1cm, single arrow head extend=0.2cm, minimum width=0.5cm] at (arrow) {text};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [Paul Gaborit's styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72793/1952) and some trial and error adjustments:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  double -latex/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{    
    -latex,line width=#1,#2,
    postaction={draw,-latex,#3,line width=(#1)/2,shorten <=(#1)/4,shorten >=4.5*(#1)/4},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[double -latex=8mm colored by black and white] (0,0)|-++(-5,-1)|- node[pos=0.65]{Text} ++(4,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to modify the arrow to have the same thin line width as the single arrow shape (sorry, this was probably not clear from my question). How can I modify the arrow tip such that it looks like the one in the single arrow?

Comment: Try with `Triangle` instead of `latex` arrow tip

Answer (score 1):

Using the Ignasi's suggestions and some trial and error, I came finally up with this solution, to have the arrow being very similar to single arrow:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.arrows}


% for arrow around corner
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    double -latex/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{    
        -{Triangle[length=0.5cm,width=0.92cm]},line width=#1,#2,
        postaction={draw,-{Triangle[length=0.46cm,width=0.84cm]},#3,line width=(#1)-2*0.2mm,
            shorten <=0.2mm, shorten >=0.22mm)},
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \node (arrow) at (0,0) {};
        \draw[double -latex=5mm colored by black and white] (arrow) -- ++ (1,0) |- (-3, -1) |- node[pos=0.8]{text} ++ (2,-2);
        \node [single arrow, draw, minimum height=1cm, single arrow head extend=0.2cm, minimum width=0.5cm] at (-1.75,-4) {text};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]