# How to highlight a path in Tikz with two different colours?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, graphs

I have a small graph drawn in Tikz with two paths through it highlighted in different colours. However, these paths are going to share an arrow. What I would like is to highlight this arrow with both colours, one above and one below so that it the reader can distinguish between these two paths. Is there a way to do this within Tikz? Below is my Tikz code for generating the picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,very thick}}
\tikzset{p1/.style={preaction={%But before that
draw,yellow,-,% Draw yellow without any arrow head
double=yellow,
double distance=.4\pgflinewidth,
}}}
\tikzset{p2/.style={preaction={%But before that
draw,green,-,% Draw green without any arrow head
double=green,
double distance=.4\pgflinewidth,
}}}
\tikz {
%%First graph
\draw[edge,densely dashed](0,0) node[label={[xshift=-.2cm,yshift=-.4cm]$w$}]{} -- (1,0) ;
\draw[edge,red,p1] (1,0) -- (2.45,.5) ;
\draw[edge,densely dashed,p1] (2.5,.5) node[label={[xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm]$w'$}]{} .. controls (3.25,1) .. (4.95,0.15);
\draw[edge,blue,p2] (1,0) -- (2.45,-.5);
\draw[edge,blue,densely dashed] (2.5,.5) -- (3.35,.10);
\draw[edge,red,densely dashed] (2.5,-.5) -- (3.35,-.10);
\draw[edge,densely dashed] (3.8,0) node[label={[xshift=-.2cm,yshift=-.4cm]$w'''$}]{}-- (5,0) node[label={[xshift=.2cm,yshift=-.4cm]$W$}]{};
\draw[edge,densely dashed,p2] (2.45,-.5) node[label={[xshift=0cm,yshift=-.8cm]$w''$}]{} .. controls (3.25,-1) .. (4.95,-0.15);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have just learned how to do this kind of thing in Tikz so apologies for what I'm sure is very bad coding style.

I'm wanting the result to look similar to [question "Two coloured arrow"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115205/two-coloured-arrow) but with the black dashed arrow still being visible (and in Tikz if at all possible). Thank you so much for any help you can give!

Edit: Here is a picture of what I'm getting at to make it clearer. Thanks again.
[image: Double Coloured Arrow]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I am confused. Let's take as example the path from `w'` to `W`; currently there's a dashed black arrow with some yellow background color. What exactly do you want the look of this arrow to be like?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  Sorry I should have clarified. The path I want to "double" highlight is the one that goes from w to the first branching point. The ones that are already coloured are as they should be. What I would like is essentially a thick block of colour that is split in the middle by the arrow, and on one side of that split it is one colour and on the other side it is the other colour. I will try and draw it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't very elegant, but you could replace the line to draw the edge from `w'''` to `W` with:

```
\draw[blue, very thick,yshift=0.7pt](3.8,0)--(4.9,0);
\draw[red,very thick,yshift=-0.7pt](3.8,0)--(4.9,0);
\draw[edge,densely dashed] (3.8,0) node[label={[xshift=-.2cm,yshift=-.4cm]$w'''$}]{}-- (5,0) node[label={[xshift=.2cm,yshift=-.4cm]$W$}]{};
```

This gives:

[image]

I am sure that there should be some fancy (and better) way of doing this with decorations/preactions, but...

Comment: Elegant enough for me :) Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\myline(#1)(#2){%
    \pnode(#1){A}
    \pnode(#2){B}
    \psset{linewidth=1}
    \pcline[offset=.5,linecolor=Yellow](A)(B)
    \pcline[offset=-.5,linecolor=Green](A)(B)
    \psline[arrowsize=0pt 2]{->}(A)(B)}

\begin{document}
\pspicture[showgrid=false](-4,-3)(4,3)
    \myline(-3,-1)(3,1)
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]